# Why when I create several html tags with javascript then I can not delete it with the same javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert, sweetalert

When I create a form with the write () command, then I want to delete it, but I can't. What is the cause of this problem?

In order to do this correctly, what command should I use or what should I change in my code?

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var btn_alert = document.querySelector('#btn-alert');
var content = document.querySelector('.popup-container');
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

function message(message, btn) {
    document.write('<div id="div1"><div id="content" class="popup-container"><div class="box-item"><div class="icon-success"><span class="span1"></span> <span class="span2"></span><div class="ring"></div></div><h2 class="alert-title">Good job!</h2><div class="alert-content">' + message + '</div><div class="actions-btn"><button onclick="ok()" class="btn-alert" id="btn-alert">' + btn + '</button></div></div></div></div>')
}

function ok() {
    div1.removeChild(content);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-alert" id="btn">OK</button>

    <!-- <div id="content" class="popup-container dis-active">
        <div class="box-item">
        <div class="icon-success">
            <span class="span1"></span> 
            <span class="span2"></span>
            <div class="ring"></div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="alert-title">Good job!</h2>
        <div class="alert-content">is ok.</div>
        <div class="actions-btn">
        <button class="btn-alert" id="btn-alert">OK</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  -->

    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        message("خوش اومدی!", "کلیک کن");
    </script>
```

Comment: `document.write` is a really a bad way to create html.  But the reason it's failing is because your getting a reference to the div before you have created it.

Comment: What method do you think I should use? If you have an article, give the link.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: This does not need the `sweetalert` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` is really outdated. In your script you write the elements to the document *after* you're trying to retrieve them. That won't work.

Here is an example snippet using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to create a message element with a button to remove it.

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers. The snippet  uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle button clicks.

It may be wise to first learn more about [html document manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) or [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
const create = () => message(`خوش اومدی!`,`کلیک کن`);

create();

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `btn-alert`) {
    document.getElementById('div1').remove();
  }
  if (evt.target.id === `recreate`) {
    create();
  }
}

function message(message, btnTxt) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeEnd`, `
    <div id="div1">
      <div id="content" class="popup-container">
        <div class="box-item">
          <div class="icon-success">
            <span class="span1"></span> 
            <span class="span2"></span>
            <div class="ring"></div>
          </div>
          <h2 class="alert-title">Good job!</h2>
          <div class="alert-content">${message}</div>
          <div class="actions-btn">
            <button class="btn-alert" id="btn-alert">${btnTxt}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
}
```

```html
<button id="recreate">(re)create message</button>
```